# PHP PDO stored procedure with INOUT parameter not updating value

Tags: php, postgresql, pdo, plpgsql

I have the following PostgreSQL (14.6) stored procedure:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE business_layer_thick_db.outtest
   ( IN OUT  p_test  VARCHAR
   )
LANGUAGE plpgsql
AS
$PROC$
   BEGIN
      p_test := 'New value!';
   END;
$PROC$
```

When I run the following anonymous PLpg/SQL in dBeaver:

```
do
$$
declare
   v_test  varchar  := 'Old value!';
begin
   raise notice '%', v_test;
   CALL business_layer_thick_db.outtest (p_test => v_test);
   raise notice '%', v_test;
end;
$$
```

... I get the following output:

**Old value!
New value!**

When I run the following PHP (8.1) code:

```
<?php
   // Report all errors
   ini_set ('display_errors', 1);
   ini_set ('display_startup_errors', 1);
   error_reporting (E_ALL);
   
   // Create PDO DB connection
   $v_user     = <<redacted>>;
   $v_password = <<redacted>>;
   $v_dsn      = "pgsql:host=<<redacted>>;port=5432;dbname=<<redacted>>;user=$v_user;password=$v_password";
   $v_options  =  [  PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE             => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION,
                     PDO::ATTR_DEFAULT_FETCH_MODE  => PDO::FETCH_ASSOC,
                     PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES    => false,
                     PDO::ATTR_ORACLE_NULLS        => PDO::NULL_EMPTY_STRING
                  ];

   try
   {
      $v_pdo = new PDO ($v_dsn, $v_user, $v_password, $v_options);
   }
   catch (\PDOException $v_exception)
   {
      throw new \PDOException ($v_exception->getMessage (), (int)$v_exception->getCode ());
   }

   $v_test = "Old value!";

   echo $v_test . "<br />";

   $v_stmt = $v_pdo->prepare ("CALL business_layer_thick_db.outtest (p_test => :v_test)");
   $v_stmt->bindParam (":v_test", $v_test, PDO::PARAM_STR|PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT, 32767);
   $v_stmt->execute ();

   echo $v_test . "<br />";
?>
```

I get the following output:

**Old value!
Old value!**

I cannot see how I am going wrong here. Advice much appreciated. Obviously, I am expecting the output for both to be:

**Old value!
New value!**

Something is clearly not right with the setup of the parameter binding.

Answer (score 0):

So, my research into this has strongly suggested there is a bug causing PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT to **not** work. And although it's long-standing, it has never been fixed.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=43887
https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46657
[PDO::PARAM_INPUT_OUTPUT not working in PostgreSQL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71340197/pdoparam-input-output-not-working-in-postgresql)

However, there is a workaround.

From line 26 of the PHP 8.1 code above, do the following instead:

```
   $v_test = "Old value!";

   echo $v_test . "<br />";

   $v_stmt = $v_pdo->prepare ("CALL business_layer_thick_db.outtest (:v_test)");
   $v_stmt->bindParam ("v_test", $v_test, PDO::PARAM_STR, 4000);
   $v_stmt->execute ();

   $v_test = $v_stmt->fetch ();

   echo var_dump ($v_test) . "<br />";
```

This is not necessarily the optimal approach, but at least demonstrates INOUT and OUT parameters can be fetched using PDOStatement::fetch() instead.